# c# speech recognition Getting some errors

Tags: c#, windows, list, case, speech-recognition

The error is CSO15IO (A constant value is expected). 
How can I fix this error and achieving the same thing.
Or is there another way to do this?
All help is appreciated!

```
public void recEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Commands_list.Count; i++)
    {
        switch (e.Result.Text)
        {
            case Commands_list[i].commandname:
                GetTime();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you have `case x:` the value `x` must be a constant, `Commands_list[i].commandname` is not a constant.

Comment: You can not use Commands_list[i].commandname as a case. So just switch it to an if-statement and it will work

Comment: Aha i see okey thnx guys i will give the if statement a try